# Python PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file..... but my file is closed

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Python program that creates a SQLite .db file, then executes a .sql script to initialize a table `TRANSACTIONS` within that db.  As part of my design, if anything fails in creating the `TRANSACTIONS` table, I want to delete the .db itself so that I'm not left with an incomplete database.

My problem is that when I try to delete the .db file with `os.remove(db_path)`, I get a Win32 error that the .db file is in use by another process.  I can't figure out what this process is.

My module, `initialize_db.py`:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import os

class initialize_db:

    # Parameters are Path objects of where to create the DB, 
    # and where to find the DB initialization script
    def __init__(self, db_path, init_script_path):
        self.db_path = db_path
        self.init_script_path = init_script_path

        try:
            self.cursor = self.create_db()
            self.initialize_transactions()
        # If an exception is raised, delete the entire database
        except ValueError:
            print('Error encountered, DB not created')
            self.cursor.close()
            os.remove(db_path)  # This is causing the issue
            raise

    def create_db(self):
        '''Creates .db database at self.db_path'''
        conn = sql.connect(self.db_path)
        print('creating database')
        return conn.cursor()

    def initialize_transactions(self):
        '''Initializes the TRANSACTIONS table within the database'''
        with open(self.init_script_path, 'r') as init_script:
            sql_script = init_script.read()

        raise ValueError  # Raise this before executing sql script as a test

        self.cursor.execute(sql_script)

        print('initialization script executed')
```

I intentionally raise a ValueError within `initialize_transactions()` to test whether my .db is deleted properly from within `__init__()`.   If I execute this, I get the following:

```
from initialize_db import initialize_db
initialize_db(my_db_path, my_db_script_path)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ...
>
> File
>   "C:\some_database_path\initialize_db.py",
>   line 26, in **init**
>
> os.remove(db_path)
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process:
>   'C:\some_database_path\database.db'

So basically, my program is creating my database, but not properly deleting it when an exception is raised.  Any thoughts on what process might be using `db_path` by the time my program gets there?  I tried investigating whether I should close a Path object, as well as my cursor, and neither seem to work.

Comment: Did you try opening the command prompt with "Run as Administrator" and then running your script?

Comment: I'm not running my program from command prompt, I'm running from within Spyder.  But, this is on a personal computer where my profile has administrative privileges.  Let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: No you didn't misunderstood me. I misunderstood the error. There is no problem with privileges. Try using "os.removedirs" instead and let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that your own process won't let you delete the database 'cause it has a handle to it. Save your `conn` like this:

```
self.conn = sql.connect(self.db_path)
```

And then, in your `except` clause, after closing the cursor, close your connection and try to delete the file:

```
self.cursor.close()
self.conn.close()
os.remove(db_path)
```

Hope it helps.